# Matplotlib legend with line and area styles

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line and area graph in the same figure with a legend that displays both the line and area styles.  Unfortunately the code below only produces lines and no areas in the legend.

Is it possible to get both lines and areas in the same legend?  If not, can I get a second legend for the area charts on the same figure?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.random.randn(6,4)), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
f, ax = plt.subplots()
df[['A','B']].plot(ax=ax, figsize=(10,5))
df[['C','D']].plot(kind='area',ax=ax, figsize=(10,5))
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image: plot of line and area graphs]

Comment: What happens if you remove `figsize`?

Comment: It just resizes the figure to a smaller one.  Legend remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

# data
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.random.randn(6,4)), 
                  index=dates, 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))

# plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
# lines A and B
lineA, = ax.plot(df.index, df['A'], color = 'black', label = 'A')
lineB, = ax.plot(df.index, df['B'], color = 'green', label = 'B')
# stacked plots
ax.fill_between(df.index, 0, df['C'], color = 'blue',label = 'C')
ax.fill_between(df.index, df['C'], df['D'], color = 'red', label = 'D')
# Labels for both stacked plots
blue_patch = patches.Patch(color='blue', label='C')
red_patch = patches.Patch(color='red', label='D')
# legend
ax.legend(handles = [lineA, lineB, blue_patch, red_patch],
          loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
# show the final plot
f.show()
```

Have a look to the [legend guide here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html?highlight=legend#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists).